# Blade Components are being handled in unexpected ways on on the server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

So here is what I know I setup a blade component and it seems that its being handled diffirently on the server than on my local

im calling the component like this:

```
<x-ui.form.text label="Email" name="email" :options='["required"=>"true"]'/>
```

Then This is the component (only the top part (error is caused right below the dd() )):

```
<div>
    @php dd($attributes) @endphp
    <div {{ $attributes->merge(['class'=>'col-12 mb-4']) }}>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 align-items-center d-flex justify-content-end">
                <label for="{{ $name }}" class="form-label mb-0">{{ $label }} @if($options['required']) <i class="bi-exclamation-circle"></i> @endif </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
                <div class="input-group has-validation">
                    @if($options['prepend'])
                    {{-- <div class="input-group-prepend border-dark"> --}}
                        <div class="input-group-text border-dark">{{ $options['prepend'] }}</div>
                    {{-- </div> --}}
                    @endif
                    <input value="{{ $value?$value:old($name) }}" class="border-dark block w-full form-control @error($name) is-invalid @enderror" type={{ $options['type'] }} id="{{ $name }}" name="{{ $name }}" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" {{ $options["readonly"]?"readonly":"" }}>
                    @if($options['append'])
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <div class="input-group-text">{{ $options['append'] }}</div>
                    </div>
```

The other part of the component looks like this:

```
public function __construct($name, $label, $value=false, $options = []) {
        $this->options = array_merge([
            "required" => false,
            "type" => "text",
            "readonly" => false,
            "prepend" => false,
            "append" => false,
        ], $options);


        $this->name = $name;
        $this->label = $label;
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->required = $this->options['required'];
    }
```

the dd in the components blade file results in this on my LOCAL env:

```
Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag {#1482 ▼ // resources\views/components/ui/form/text.blade.php
  #attributes: []
}
```

But on the server it results in this:

```
Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag {#1405 ▼ // resources/views/components/ui/form/text.blade.php
  #attributes: array:3 [▼
    "label" => "Email"
    "name" => "email"
    "options" => []
  ]
}
```

on my local it works perfectly without issues, I even did a checkout on my home media server to see if it had something to do with the apache server but that seems fine it works there aswell

- local runs windows 11
- media server windows 10
- hosting linux

but with the hosting company it causes this error.

Pages without any components on them works perfectly fine.

Things that might be of note:

1. I copied component folders from another project over to this one
2. I tried adding/removing/swapping the single and double quotes of the array
3. I tried adding/removing/swapping the single and double quotes of the array
4. I tried removing the component (this worked but only if I removed all the components on the page)
5. If I remove the options attributes it complains its not set eventhough it is set to default in the component php file
6. I double/triple checked the env file and its correct (I cant see that this is a issue because pages without components work fine
7. I checked paths and file premissions
8. I checked composer packeges

Everything looks right

I dont know if this will have a effect but my hosting company has a base php version of php8.0
when I SSH to them and I run php -v I get version 8.0 but on my control panel I have it set to 8.2, when displaying phpinfo() from the browser I see version 8.2 to run version 8.2 in terminal I need to use `/usr/bin/php-wrapper`.

Composer was also a issue they run v1 of composer because they have old projects that still use it but they assisted me with installing v2 to my user so running composer I need to use this `/usr/home/{username}/composer` doing somting like composer update I need to combine the lines else when generating the auto load composer complains about the php version being to low so that looks something like this `/usr/bin/php-wrapper /usr/home/{username}/composer update --no-dev`

Any ideas on why this would be happening?